# How can I propagate Exception Messages at architecture level?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I am working on a project where if exception is raised at Server side, the thrown exception is propagated in backward ways towards client via ... proxy,... clientRepository, and shows in MessageBox at client end. Also Logger do Logging at every phase.

At this point of time, things are working the way I want, but now I am planing to Internationalize these messages using Resource file for each language. In this way how can I work to make it available on client end ? I need optimum (Less overhead) and efficient (Scalable) way for this.

Comment: This is broad topic and your question should be closed. But I can tell you that I would look into making system using request-response mechanics. So, instead of `int ordId = BLL.Orders.Save(order)`, I would do  `Response r = BLL.Orders.Save(order); if (!r.Success) MessageBox.Show(r.Message);`. So, now you don't care how to translate your message because it is created in language concrete user operates in. Another point is, with resource file based globalization, it is not robust enough. Think about DB-driven globalization.

Comment: Not sure I understand your situation, but what @T.S. says about getting the message created in the desired language so you don't need to translate it can maybe be done in another way. Can you set the current language for the server side program to the language of the client each time you are processing a request from a client using a different language? This may mean you need to install a multi-language pack on the server, but that should not be a problem, and in fact I don't think it is necessary.